# Make leaflet layers control with checkboxes, not radio buttons?

Tags: javascript, leaflet

Is there an easy way to make a [leaflet layers control](http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.1.0.html#control-layers) (`L.control.layers`) use checkboxes rather than radio buttons?

I have multiple WMS tile layers, and I'd like to be able to have more than one on the map at the same time. For context, the WMS tile layers include bathymetry and contours (topo lines), so it'd be more informative to visualize both at the same time, rather than just having some lines floating in the ocean.

In the [leaflet example](http://leafletjs.com/examples/layers-control/) it says the layers control is "smart enough" to know which to assign radio buttons and which checkboxes, but it'd be nice to have more customized control.

Relevant code:

`L.control.layers(WMS, null, {collapsed: false}).addTo(map);`
where `WMS` is multiple `L.tileLayer.wms` layers.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Pass your `WMS` as the 2nd argument (i.e. as overlays) instead of the 1st (basemaps) of `L.control.layers`.

Overlays use check boxes, whereas basemaps use radio buttons.

Comment: awesome, i checked for that ability along time ago, and i didnt find the solution. now i have check it, and it works! Thanks man.

Answer (score 6):

Here i create an [example](http://jsfiddle.net/iofirag/Ltub5bgv/18/) to demonstrate what ghybs said.

```
L.control.layers(null, mixed).addTo(map);
```

Checkout my jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/iofirag/Ltub5bgv/18/.

Comment: I wish that I could upvote this more than once. It's a great example.

Comment: Thanks! I was glad to help :)